# Program terminates without any error

Tags: java, python, windows, yelp

I am trying to run this Python program in Java.

**Issue:**
When i run this program from Commandline: **Python msp.py dennys-san-jose-2** - it **WORKS**

When I call the same script through this java program. It just terminates. **I tested other python scripts and they work!**

```
public void pythonrun(String args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    String pythonScriptPath = "/yelp/msp.py";
    String[] cmd = new String[2 + args.length()];
    cmd[0] = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
    cmd[1] = pythonScriptPath;
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length(); i++) {
    cmd[i+2] = args;
    }

    // create runtime to execute external command
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);
    //pr.waitFor();

    // retrieve output from python script
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
    // display each output line form python script
    System.out.println(line);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
YelpPython demo = new YelpPython();
demo.pythonrun("dennys-san-jose-2");
}
```

**Script (msp.py):**

What it does? *(in short, the script goes to a page and scrapes the reviews)*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
import sys
queries = 0
while queries <201:
    stringQ = sys.argv[1]
    page = urlopen('http://www.yelp.com/biz/' + stringQ)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    reviews = soup.findAll('p', attrs={'itemprop':'description'})
    authors = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'itemprop':'author'})

    flag = True
    indexOf = 1

    for review in reviews:
        dirtyEntry = str(review)
        while dirtyEntry.index('<') != -1:
            indexOf = dirtyEntry.index('<')
            endOf = dirtyEntry.index('>')
            if flag:
                dirtyEntry = dirtyEntry[endOf+1:]
                flag = False
            else:
                if(endOf+1 == len(dirtyEntry)):
                    cleanEntry = dirtyEntry[0:indexOf]
                    break
                else:
                    dirtyEntry = dirtyEntry[0:indexOf]+dirtyEntry[endOf+1:]
        f=open("reviews.txt", "a")
        f.write(cleanEntry)
        f.write("\n")
        f.close
    queries = queries + 40
```

**Problem (In short):**

When I run this script through command line it works and it finally stores a **reviews.txt** file. But when I run it through this program nothing happens.

I have played with pr.wait() and pr.waitfor() and yet nothing happens.

Please advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void pythonrun(String args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String pythonScriptPath = "/yelp/msp.py";
    String[] cmd = new String[2 + args.length()];
    cmd[0] = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
    cmd[1] = pythonScriptPath;
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length(); i++) {
        cmd[i+2] = args;
    }
    :
}
```

That doesn't look quite right. You're creating a string array with a size based on the size of the *string* being passed in.

That means that `pythonrun("1234")` will end up executing:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe /yel/msp.py 1234 1234 1234 1234
```

If you just want to pass in a single argument for the script, you would do something like:

```
public void pythonrun(String args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String pythonScriptPath = "/yelp/msp.py";
    String[] cmd = new String[3];
    cmd[0] = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
    cmd[1] = pythonScriptPath;
    cmd[2] = args;
    :
}
```

If you wanted to pass in an *array* of arguments, something like this would be better:

```
public void pythonrun(String [] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String pythonScriptPath = "/yelp/msp.py";
    String[] cmd = new String[2 + args.length()];
    cmd[0] = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
    cmd[1] = pythonScriptPath;
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length(); i++) {
        cmd[i+2] = args[i];
    }
    :
}
```

You can tell *exactly* what parameters are being used for the process by placing the following code after the code where you set them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cmd.length(); i++)
    System.out.println ("DEBUG " + i + ": [" + cmd[i] + "]");
```

---

Beyond that, there may be discrepencies between your command line version and the one called from your Java program.

For one thing, your Java program is calling `/yelp/msp.py` whereas your command line version call `msp.py` directly. Are you sure that your `msp.py` script is actually *in* `/yelp`?

Also make sure that `C:\Python27\python.exe` is the correct Python interpreter.

And, one last thing, check which directory you're in when the Java program is running. If it's not what you expect, you may well be creating `reviews.txt` in a totally unexpected place.

Comment: Could you help me fix it? I am just trying to pass that string as an argument. How can I modify this script to suit my needs? I'm passing "dennys-san-jose-2" or something similar.

Comment: @Rocky, I've added two possibilities to the answer, one if you just want a single argument, the other if you wish to pass in an array of strings.

Comment: Man you're a lifesaver! `SO` rocks! I'll check back and let you know!

Comment: Same issue. It still executes. Nothing happens

Comment: thanks for your reply. I just checked. it's in `/yelp/msp.py` and I am able to run other scripts with the same code. I believe `reviews.txt` should be created in the same directory where the msp.py isn't it? (it's in my `eclipseworkspace/project)`

Comment: @Rocky, no, it will be created in whatever the current directory is. If you want to make sure it's created in the same directory as your Python script, use `f=open("/yelp/reviews.txt", "a")`.

Comment: Can anyone commend please? I am still trying to fix this wierd problem. I don't know why my code does not run on Eclipse but executes when I try it using command line. Should I change my OS from windows to linux and then try?

Comment: Hello @paxdiablo thanks for helping. I managed to find the solution and I have listed it. But it's a strange behaviour !!

Answer (score 0):

```
String python_script_path ="Path to Python script/";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python","msp.py","parameter1","parameter2");
 pb.directory(new File(python_script_path));
Process process = pb.start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line1;
 while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
 System.out.println(line1);
 }
```

Use Processbuilder and set path variables

Comment: I am trying to run this but the script itself gives me an error when I use /yelp/msp.py .. Can i know what is wrong with my current one? cuz it works for all other python scripts

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the solution for this one although I still don't get it.

I used the same code and it works on Ubuntu.

```
cmd[0] = "python";
```

This is all I modified and I ran the same script and b00m and it works!

The question is **WHY?**